# How to use Google Analytics web+api property to fetch analytics data and display on third party dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

AS Google Analytics Services SDK  sunset On October 31st, 2019 they stop processing incoming hits for this property. and ask to use latest App + Web property, which utilizes Google Analytics for Firebase SDK.

I have successfully linked firebase with app+web property.

Now my question is , how i can fetch that analytics data useing that property ID and display on third party website? I am successfully able to capture app analytics data i just want to display that report with API. how i can use propertyID to fetch that data.

With web_app property there is no View(ViewID) as previous.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public API to get the firebase-backed App + Web analytics data. However, you might have enabled BigQuery integration and use BigQuery API to make requests to analytics tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any public statement from Google/Firebase that confirms this?

Comment: *firebaser here* While this answer was correct at the time of posting, there **is** now actually an API to get data directly from the dashboard too. See [Brett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64415862/209103) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For GA4 Properties, you can use the Google Analytics Data API v1 to fetch analytics data and display on a third party site. This API can produce reports of active users by date and other useful dashboards.

See the Data API v1's developers site for more information: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data

When fetching analytics data in the Analytics v3 and Analytics Reporting v4 APIs, a view id is specified. As the question suggests, GA4 properties do not have views. GA4 properties cannot be used in Analytics v3 and Analytics Reporting v4 APIs.

This question asks about "App + Web" properties. For context, App + Web Properties were recently renamed to GA4 Properties. See the blog post for more information: https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new_google_analytics/